# Selenium (Python) - Get webdriver's page_source after page is fully loaded

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have to get data from a dynamic page (many of them in fact). I can access the page using Selenium in Python. However, the driver.page_source is incomplete. Even if I try driver.implicitly_wait(100) nothing changes.

I also tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Load all")))
```

While I see some waiting / pausing, more than enough for the page to load, I see no effect on driver.page_source after the wait.

Is there a solution here?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you need `page_source` for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use something other for grabbing the page source if you really need it. Webdrivers' `getPageSource` will just return *some state in some formatting* of the last page the driver was on.

From the (java)docs, but most probably applies to other languages:

> ```
> getPageSource
>
> java.lang.String getPageSource()
> ```
>
> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified after loading
>   (for example, by Javascript) there is no
>   guarantee that the returned text is that of the modified page. Please
>   consult the documentation of the particular driver being used to
>   determine whether the returned text reflects the current state of the
>   page or the text last sent by the web server. The page source returned
>   is a representation of the underlying DOM: do not expect it to be
>   formatted or escaped in the same way as the response sent from the web
>   server. Think of it as an artist's impression.
>
> ```
> Returns:
>     The source of the current page
> ```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29